# AxiosError: Network Error in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, axios

I encountered this problem after updating macOS to sonoma API requests do not work at all, although before this update it worked and after building the apk on a real phone it does not work!

I tried everything but to no avail.

Comment: Are you able to make API requests in your virtual device or the issue is happening only in physical device?